# Why $\left|\int f f^{q-1}\right|=\|f\|_q^q$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in \mathcal C_0^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ and $q=\frac{2d}{2d-2s}$. We denote $$(f,g):=\int_{\mathbb R^d} fg.$$
In the proof of the theorem 1.1 (page 6 of [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022247X04002471/1-s2.0-S0022247X04002471-main.pdf?_tid=c414553e-f307-11e7-b6d7-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1515260214_5efe4b395954596319380dfaa489c6a8)), just uner the formula (15), they say that for $g=f^{q-1}$ we have $$|(f,g)|=|(f,f^{q-1})|\underset{(*)}{=}\|f\|_{q}^q,$$
and I don't understand why we have the equality $(*)$. I agree that $$|(f,f^{q-1})|=\left|\int_{\mathbb R^d}f^q\right|\leq \int_{\mathbb R^d}|f|^q=\|f\|_q^q,$$
but why do we have the equality ?

Comment: You seem to be correct. I do not feel like reading through the paper, but is one okay if one instead takes $g$ to be $f^{q-1}\overline{sgn(f)}$ so that $fg = |f|^q$?

Comment: @mathworker21: thanks for your answer and your idea.

Comment: does that  work?